# How to refresh OpenCV window when I combine it with pyAutoGui

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, pyautogui

So im trying to make a program that moves my mouse cursor and clicks every black pixel found on the screen.

I got to the point where I can input the screen, see it in a window and even let the mouse click on the black pixels. Without the clicking part in the program, I can see the windows changing in real time, but if I add the clicking part it stops refreshing.

```py
 import numpy as np
 import pyautogui as py
 from PIL import ImageGrab
 import cv2 as cv

 while(True):

     # Record location of the program
     screen_size = [1293, 171, 1647, 769]

     screen = np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox=screen_size))
     cv.imshow("window", cv.cvtColor(screen, cv.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY))

     # Quit
     if cv.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
         cv.destroyAllWindows()
         break

     for y in range(len(screen)):
         for x in range(len(screen[y])):
             if np.any(screen[y][x]) == 0:
                  py.click(x+1293,y+171)
```

I would like to have the screen refresh or something like that, so that lets say it looks at an video of black dots, it can see them and click on all of them. Now it is just stuck at the starting image and keeps clicking the starting dots even when they arent visiable anymore.

This is a video of the problem:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QIrEnCgxe6E&feature=youtu.be

You can see here how it follows the black lines perfectly, but the window OpenCV creates doesnt change, and when I draw over some of the black parts, it still draws over it.

This is the window I see and how it converts the colors

[image: Window]

Answer (score 0):

The screen doesn't refresh/update, because the program is still working on the double for-loop that clicks all black pixels. If you want to use this for real-time video it is obviously way to slow a process. You could look into findContours, to click once on every black area. This will be much faster and gives the behavior that I think you want.

Below is some sample code that shows how findContours works. [Here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_table_of_contents_contours/py_table_of_contents_contours.html) is additional info / examples.

Result:
[image]

Code:

```
     # load image
    img = cv2.imread("image.png")
    # convert to gray
    gray =  cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # create a mask that hold only black values (below 10) 
    ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(gray,10,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    # find contours in mask
    ret, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh1, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    # draw outline of contour on image
    for cnt in contours:
            cv2.drawContours(img, [cnt], 0, (255,0,0), 2) 
    #show image
    cv2.imshow("img", img)

    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```